# Socks from a Box - 3 matching socks

Tags: probability

Let's say we have a box filled with socks: three pairs each of white, gray, and black socks (i.e. six socks of each of the three colors, for eighteen socks in total). We draw socks randomly from the box without replacement.

Let's say we draw three socks from the box. What is the probability that we draw the same color for all three socks?

Comment: **Hint:** We don't care what the first sock's color is... it is whatever.  The second sock should match the first but there are only five of that color remaining in the drawer out of seventeen remaining socks at the time.  The third sock should then also match...  Apply the [multiplication rule of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_(probability))

Answer (score 0):

Say you draw one sock. The probability of drawing any particular color, say black, is $\frac{6}{18}=\frac{1}{3}$. Then, there are $17$ socks remaining, of which only $5$ are black. The probability of drawing one of five black socks from $17$ total socks is $\frac{5}{17}$. Similarly, the probability of drawing one of four black socks from $16$ total socks is $\frac{4}{16}=\frac{1}{4}$.

Thus, the probability of drawing three black socks is $\frac{1}{3}\frac{5}{17}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{204}\approx0.0245$.

**Edit:** As mentioned by @Ross in the comments, since the color choice does not matter as long as all three socks are the same color, the final answer is this times $3$, or $3\cdot\frac{1}{3}\frac{5}{17}\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{68}\approx0.0735$.

Comment: Now you have to multiply by $3$ because there are three different colors.  The chance of getting three of any color is the same. The question does not specify three black socks.

Comment: @Ross Yes, of course, that was an oversight. I'll edit the answer accordingly.